# Identity Theorem: Extending from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

Suppose we have $f_1, f_2: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic, and $f_1 = f_2$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Can we then say $f_1 = f_2$ identically on $\mathbb{C}$?

This appears to be true by the uniqueness of analytic continuations, but the identity theorem requires that the functions must agree on an open set, and clearly $\mathbb{R}$ is not open with respect to $\mathbb{C}$.

Assuming the above is true, why can this not be shown using the identity theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The identity theorem does not require that the functions must agree on an open set !

Let $A:=\{z \in \mathbb C:f_1(z)=f_2(z)\}$ .

If $A$ has an accumulation point in $ \mathbb C$, then , by the identitiy theorem, $f_1=f_2$ on $ \mathbb C$.

In your case we have $A = \mathbb R$.

Comment: It seems I've fallen foul of the Wikipedia article on the Identity Theorem which (incorrectly?) states in the first line that the Identity Theorem requires an open set, and then later on the in the article relaxes the condition to include sets with an accumulation point in the domain.

Comment: The first version of the identity thoerem is not incorrect. This first version is only less general.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is true. For the identity theorem, it is enough to assume that $f_1 = f_2$ on a set with at least one accumulation point.